# Backbone events fail because of multiple re-rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Recently I've started using backbone and really liked its simplicity and flexibility. Though, currently i'm facing a problem: due to constant view re-rendering, the buttons and links are not working as they should and I need to click several times to 'catch' the button between the renderings.

I'm following this logics in my app:

- init a backbone collection which holds the models for progress bars
- attach a 'change' event listener to this collection and re-render view in a callback
- receive data for progress bar via websocket and update a correspondent model in a collection
- render a template with underscore

Although, visually everything is fine and i don't see any delays, somehow the links, which are rendered in same template with progress bars are not working.

Is there any solution for such an issue apart from updating certain parts of template via jquery?

Comment: Please provide some code (and a fiddle with the problem) so we can actually see what's going on. Anyway, using `delegateEvents` can solve some issues occuring when attaching events to elements while rendering. http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents

Comment: Pasted a code sample to https://jsfiddle.net/j384015j/1/
<a class="download_url"> is an example of link that doesnt work

Comment: @EugeneSue re-rendering entire view for every socket message is a bad idea. Backbone isn't designed to work real time that way. You should write code to just update the CSS or whatever of your slider rather than completely re-rendering it

Comment: provide some code we can't help you